# Finding the de Rham Cohomology group of $\mathbb{S}^2\backslash \{a,b,c\}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

I am trying to understand how to compute the de Rham cohomology group. Could someone show me how I would find the cohomology group of $\mathbb{S}^2\backslash\{n\text{ points of } \mathbb{S}^2 \}$. I know I should find the de Rham cohomology group for $n=1,2,3,4,..$ till I see a pattern. However, I have little experience doing this and can't find a good example I could follow. Could someone show me how to compute these for several n-values?

Comment: Look up Alexander duality theorem.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{S}$? Is it $S^1$?

Comment: Sorry, it was suppose to be $\mathbb{S}^2$. I edited.

Comment: Alternatively, your space is homotopic to the join of two circles.

Comment: Do you know Mater viertoris sequence?

Comment: @JohnMa I know what Mater viertoris sequences are. I think that is what I am suppose to use to solve the problem but that is precisely what I don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\mathbb S^2\setminus\{\text{point}\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$, we focus on the question of finding the deRham cohomology group

$$H^1(\mathbb R^2 \setminus\{p_1, \cdots, p_n\})$$

for all $n$ and $i=1,2$. For simplicity write $X_n  = \mathbb R^2 \setminus\{p_1, \cdots, p_n\}$. We show by induction that

> $H^2(X_n) = 0$, while $H^1(X_n) \cong \mathbb R^n$.

The case $n=0$ is trivial (Poincare lemma). Assume the above for some $n-1$. By a diffeomorphism, one may assume that $p_i = (i,0) \in \mathbb R^2$.

Let $X_n^+ = X_{n-1} \setminus\{ (i, t): t\ge 0\}$ and  $X_n^- = X_{n-1} \setminus\{ (i, t): t\le 0\}$. Then

$$ X_n^+ \cup X_n^- = X_n, \ \ X_n^+ \cap X_n^- \cong X_{n-1} \cup R,$$

where $R = (p_n,\infty) \times \mathbb R$. Using (part of) the MV sequence, which is

$$\to H^1(X_n^+) \oplus H^1(X_n^-)  \overset{g}{\to}  H^1(X_{n-1} \cup R)  \to H^2(X_n) \to 0$$

Note that $X_n^\pm \cong X_{n-1}$ and $g$ is given by $g(a, b) = a-b$ (Note $H^1(X_{n-1} \cup R) = H^1(X_{n-1})$). This shows that $H^2(X_n) = 0$ as $g$ is surjective. On the other hand, using

$$H^0(X_n^+)\oplus H^0(X_n^-)\to H^0(X_{n-1} \cup R)\overset{d^*}{\to} H^1(X_n) \to H^1(X_n^+) \oplus H^1(X_n^-) \to $$

The first two groups are both $\mathbb R^2$ and the maps between them is $(s, t) \mapsto (s-t,s-t)$. Together with the expression for $g$, we see that $H^1(X_n)$ is $n$-dimensional. Thus the assertion is proved by induction.